# Arquivo XML sem informação de estilo associada

Tags: xml

Qual é o significado desta mensagem?

> This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated
>   with it. The document tree is shown below.

Tenho esta mensagem em um arquivo XML gerado dinamicamente e não sei o que quer dizer exatamente esta mensagem.

Comment: passa o arquivo num validador de xml: http://www.xmlvalidation.com/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Tradução:

> Este arquivo XML aparenta não ter nenhuma informação de estilo associada. A árvore do documento está exibida abaixo

Quer dizer que o XML não dá nenhuma dica para o browser sobre como exibir seu conteúdo, e portanto o browser vai usar a apresentação padrão, em forma de árvore. Isso é uma mensagem do browser, absolutamente normal caso seu XML não tenha um CSS associado.